# Непонятная ошибка Java Script

Tags: javascript

При попытке выполнить код вылезает странная ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
            <script src="common.js"></script>
            <script >
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    function output()
                    {
                        alert("testing RadioButton events");
                    }
                });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form id="form">
                <input type="text"  id="lol1" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя" required />
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <input type="text" id="lol2" name="phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон" required />
                <br />
                <button id="lol3" onClick="output()">Отправить</button>
            </form>
            <?php
            //echo $name ;
            //echo $phone ;
            ?>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: используешь какой-нибудь `adBlock`?

Comment: да, но когда вставляю какой нибудь другой чужой код, все работает

Comment: вот он и блокирует. что внутри `common.js`?

Comment: а можно более подробно? что исправить. для чайников

Comment: @AlexanderMelnikov, не использовать рекламу, либо отключить adblock

Comment: @Grundy, не помогло

Comment: @AlexanderMelnikov, что не помогло? :-)

Comment: @Grundy рекламы нет, adblock отключил

Comment: @AlexanderMelnikov, откуда ты знаешь что рекламы нет? если что-то блочит запрос, значит этот запрос откуда-то идет.

Comment: @Grundy, я просто не понимаю откуда ей взяться. Хостинг платный, в папке лежит всего два файла с минимальным кодом

Comment: во вкладке network браузера можно в колонке initiator - увидеть откуда идет вызов

Comment: @Sublihim, не до конца отформатировал

Comment: @Grundy не вижу :-/

Comment: @Sublihim, `</script>
    </head>`

Comment: @Grundy поправил